# What can I use instead of the id attribute, in case there might be a duplicate?

Tags: javascript, html

I know almost any item in the DOM can have an "id" attribute, and I've been using it to keep track of each client in a table of clients. I also am aware, that you are not supposed to have any id be repeated. In my code, the id of the row is set to each person's "clientId", which comes from a unique key in a database, so there will be no repeats... but elsewhere on the page is an "issues" table, where i have been setting the id of each row to the "issueId" (again a unique key), but I realized that a clientId, could potentially match an issueId, and I don't know the consequence.

I'm looking for a way to identify the each row so I can call them up later. Is there another attribute I can use that would be preferred for this? should I just add the word "client" in front of the number when assigning the id's? I want to use standard practices and have a fast web app here.

It's ok if a client and a issue number match because I will always know which one I'm looking for and I can drill down to the table first when looking for it. I just don't want to use "id" because its illegal to have id's repeat. For example if I'm looking for an issue I can use something like. `document.getElementById("issueTable").getElementBySOMETHING(issueId)` instead of just `document.getElementBySOMETHING(issueId)`

Comment: Why not prefix the ids with "client-X" or "issue-X"?

Comment: @JanDvorak, actually, [IDs can start with digits in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: @zzzzBov whilst an ID can start with digits, I've encountered before that a CSS interpreter won't accept digits first with the `#id` or `.class` notation.

Comment: @PaulS, yes, older browsers that don't support HTML5 will have issues just like they would if they didn't support `border-radius` or `box-shadow`.

Comment: currently they are numbers-only. I didn't even know that was a problem...is it just really old browsers? seems to work fine on safari, chrome, and firefox.

Comment: @VoltzRoad The issue is more to do with CSS rules than JavaScript getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that there are no conflicts, you could add a unique prefix to your *id* values, for example, `client-X` or `issue-X`.
Now, even if they share the same key, the *id* attribute is different for each due to this prefix. You could then modify your lookup code as follows

```
document.getElementById('issue-'+key); // get by issue
document.getElementById('client-'+key); // get by client
```

This means you can get your element in one lookup and using `getElementById` which is one of [the fastest methods](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/28). Furthermore, this method means you won't have previous generation browsers have trouble with a key beginning with a number should you want to use a CSS rule to style the element differently.

Comment: +1 for best available option. Could just chop it down to i-X and c-X.

Comment: @DominicB-c yep, but never forget the benefits of having clear code in production!

Comment: whats the easiest way to pull back out the numeric id then, in case I need the number by itself to send to the database?

Comment: From an element's ID attribute, you could get this value back by `var key = elm.id.slice('issue-'.length)`, or store it in additional places such as a _data-* attribute_ (although you should already know it since you already got the element).

Answer (score 3):

Use `class` instead of `id`.

```
getElementsByClassName(); // needs a shim for IE8 and lower
```

Comment: so you're suggesting that in case of collision, the confusion is carried on? Read the question please.

Comment: @JanDvorak, no thesystem has it right, just without enough detail, give a class to all the `issue` items, and a class to all the `client` items, and use some `data-*` attributes to pass necessary data to the DOM.

Comment: @zzzzBov so to recap... you're saying I should give the table a class, and then it will be inherited by each row? and then instead of "id", I will set a made up "data-clientId" (or "data-issueId") attribute for each row... But then How do I find them by the clientId? `document.getElementByClassName("clientsClass").WHATGOESHERE(clientId)` ?

Comment: @VoltzRoad, `document.querySelector('[data-client-id="5"]')` will get you the item with the `data-client-id` attribute of `5`. At this point I generally recommend using jQuery to normalize selectors cross-browser, but it really depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

**getElementById()** - Returns a reference to the element by its ID.

**getElementsByClassName()** - Returns a set of elements which have all the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

**getElementsByTagName()** - Returns a list of elements with the given tag name. The subtree underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element itself. The returned list is live, meaning that it updates itself with the DOM tree automatically. Consequently, there is no need to call several times element.getElementsByTagName with the same element and arguments.

**querySelectorAll()** - Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

*Fonts:*

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/